# Chrome Issue : overflow-x element scrolled by dragging

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow

As title.Below is a test in win7/Chrome27/IE9/FF22.

style:

```
.outer{
    width : 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x : hidden;
    overflow-y : auto;
}

.inner{
    border-left:400px solid red;
    border-right: 400px solid green;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Only the left red part could be see in IE/FF.

But in Chrome the inner element could be drag to right side.Is it a chrome's issue? And how avoid it?

Normal(ie/ff):

[image]

Unnormal(chrome):

[image]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LULDC/

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @AndréDion 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: Your fiddle does not reproduce the error for me in Chrome 27.0.1453.116 running in Mac OS X (10.7)

Comment: Chrome 29.0.1547.0, win7, shows all red. Is it possible an add-on is changing the style? Or it may be fixed between Chrome versions.

Comment: Using 27.0.1453.116 in Windows 7 and cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:y; to your .inner class

```
.inner{
    border-left:400px solid red;
    border-right: 400px solid green;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
    overflow:y;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LULDC/

No more scrolling with click and drag!